# I have some problems related to Javascript and HTML5 Canvas element and PHP CURL within my game

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, html, canvas

I have made a game using HTML5 Canvas Element, Javascript for facebook. There are two problems I am facing.

## PROBLEM 1

1.My game is inside an iframe in the facebook app so when I use the **onkeydown** even of Javascript and press down arrow key, the game works normally but the scrollbars go up and down. I have uploaded the game and set it up already. It can be found at: [snake](http://apps.facebook.com/snaqe_game/).

## PROBLEM 2

2.I totally can't understand how to use the graph API, since I have no knowledge of cURL, for posting the score earned on the wall without asking the player since if I ask them just like "facebook wants me to" the player can change it.

Comment: You should ask two questions for 2 questions ... ehm problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop facebook scrollbars from moving after using javascript onkeydown event for a canvas game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303247/how-to-stop-facebook-scrollbars-from-moving-after-using-javascript-onkeydown-even)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This was asked earlier and now I have asked that one again.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You must use some method to stop event from bubbling or captured by parent:

for IE

```
window.event.cancelBubble = true
```

For Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera

```
e.stopPropagation()
e.preventDefault()
```

For more info read this document: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

**2.** You need to use ajax to submit score from user browser, not from server, because of you will have not user's authentication's token/cookie which use to identify what's user submitting the score. If you use ajax then browser will automatically push cookie together with request then you don't care about that.