# How to stop facebook scrollbars from moving after using javascript onkeydown event for a canvas game?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, canvas

I have made a game using HTML5 Canvas Element, Javascript for facebook. You can visit it here, http://apps.facebook.com/snaqe_game. The problem I am facing is that when I press down arrow key, used for moving the snake implemented using Javascript *onkeydown* event, the game works normally but the scrollbars go up and down. I tried making an textbox(#activ) and setting focus to it. It worked but when I tried to make it invisible, it failed.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('activ').focus()
    if (!allowPressKeys) {
        return null;
    }
    var keyCode;
    if(event == null) {
        keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        keyCode = event.keyCode;
    }

    switch(keyCode) {
        case 37:
            if (direction != "right") {
                moveLeft();
            }
            break;

        case 38:
            if (direction != "down") {
                moveUp();
            }
            break;

        case 39:
            if (direction != "left") {
                moveRight();
            }
            break;

        case 40:
            if (direction != "up") {
                moveDown();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `document.onkeydown` function (after line 197 in `snake.js`), add

```
if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }
if (event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); }
return false;
```

This prevents the browser from responding to the event, beyond executing your function.

You may also need to replace `return null;` on line 161 with these three lines.

---

- [event.stopPropagation in the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation)
- [event.preventDefault in the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault)
- [Early Event Handlers: Prevent Default at QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link4)